# Unit testing nested promises fails with timeout

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise, mocha.js

I've got a wrapper around the Axios XHR library, and I'm trying to write some unit tests for my code.  However, when I run my tests, they all fail telling me that the timeout exceeded.  How do I need to structure my tests in order to run my assertions?

Here's the wrapper code:

```
export const clientRequest = (xhrClient, endpoint, params = {}) => {
  const method = params.method || 'get'
  const {config, data, noOrg, unrestricted} = params

  let reqParams = data
  if (!isNil(data) && method === 'get') {
    reqParams = {params: data}
  }

  const authConfig = unrestricted ? {...config, withCredentials: false} :
    {...config, withCredentials: true}

  const concatEndpoint = noOrg ? endpoint :
    `${Cookies.get('organization') || 'default' }${endpoint}`

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    xhrClient[method](concatEndpoint, reqParams, authConfig)
      .then(response => resolve(response))
      .catch(err => reject(err))
  })
}
```

And the test in question:

```
  describe('clientRequest()', () => {
    const resolveSpy = sinon.spy()
    const fakeClient = {
      get: () => new Promise(resolveSpy),
    }

    it.only('should make a call to the supplied method', (done) => {
      const result = xhr.clientRequest(fakeClient, '/foobar', {method: 'get'})
      result.then(() => {
        expect(resolveSpy).to.have.beenCalledWith('/foobar', undefined, {withCredentials: true})
        done()
      })
    })
  })
```

Comment: I don't think I can answer your question. However, I have one comment about your use of promises... Your `clientRequest` function ends with a return value that is a new promise that contains within its body a `then` reaction. This seems to go against what I've learned about promises, in that nested promises are usually (always?) an anti-pattern and should be flattened. This may or may not be relevant to your immediate problem, and I could perhaps be missing the point of your code, but you may want to look into this further.

Comment: A couple of questions and a note: 1. is the result promise calling the `then` content? 2. are you sure you don't need to setup the `spy` and the `fakeClient` in a `before` block? Note: You can just return the promise in the test without using the `done` callback (mocha understand `Promises` and wait the returned one to complete)

Comment: @MarcoL removing the `done` callback seems to have worked.  I wonder why it would cause it to fail?

Comment: If you remove the 'done' callback you're not test anything but returning in a synchronous way. Basically you're not testing anything. Try to remove the done callback and return the 'result.then()' promise.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `fakeClient.get` is never resolving.

Since it is the method that should be spied upon, I would suggest to change `fakeClient` this way:

```
const fakeClient = {
  get: () => Promise.resolve()
}
sinon.spy(fakeClient, 'get');
```

It is also vital to add a `catch` call in order to handle errors in the promise chain:

```
result.then(() => {
  expect(resolveSpy).to.have.beenCalledWith('/foobar', undefined, {withCredentials: true})
  done()
}).catch(done);
```

Comment: By the way, `.then(response => resolve(response))` could be easily replaced with just `.then(resolve)`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately, the solution didn't work, It still times out.

Comment: @KevinWhitaker I've updated the answer - it's probably the missing `catch`.

Comment: There's no need to catch. Just return that statement and 'mocha' will catch internally

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following @MarcoL's suggestion and returned the expectation.

```
it('should make a call to the supplied method', () => {
  const result = xhr.clientRequest(fakeClient, '/foobar', {method: 'get'})
  return result.then(() => (
    expect(resolveSpy).to.have.been.calledWith('/foobar', undefined, {withCredentials: true})
  ))
})
```